# awk counting number of digits within a given range

Tags: awk

How can I count the number of times a digit within a given range of numbers in a field occurs?

For example, the raw text `foo.txt` is shown below:

```
2,3,4,2,4
2,3,4,32,4
2,3,4,12,4
2,3,4,4,4
2,3,4,,4
2,3,4,15,4
2,3,4,15,4
```

I want to count the number of times a digit in field #4 falls between the following ranges: [0,10) and [10,20), where the lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is not.

The result should be:

range 0-10: 2
range 10-20: 3

Here is my awk code below, but I am getting 8600001 for both ranges,
`awk -f prog.awk foo.txt`:

```
#!/usr/range/awk
# prog.awk

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    $range1=0;
    $range2=0;
}
$4 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 >= 0 && $4 < 10 { $range1 += 1 };
$4 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 >= 10 && $4 < 20 { $range2 += 1 };
END {
    print $range1, "\t", $range2;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean 'digits' or 'numbers'?  Digits are single numerals; they're also numbers, of course, but `10` is a single number represented by two digits.  Judging from the expected output for column 4, you're counting numbers, not digits.  The interesting case is the empty field; it will be very easy to count that as a zero rather than as an empty field with no number in it.

Comment: Note that `awk` uses `$` to indicate a field number, not a general variable.  In the initialization, `$range1 = 0` sets `$0` to `0` because `range1` is not defined, so it is equivalent to zero as a number or an empty string.  Drop the `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '$4>=0{a[int($4/10)]++} 
             END{print "range 0-10:" a[0],"range 10-20:" a[1]}' file

range 0-10:2 range 10-20:3
```

can be easily expanded to cover the full range

```
$ awk -F, '$4>=0{a[int($4/10)]++} 
             END{for(k in a) print "range ["k*10"-"(k+1)*10"):", a[k]}' file

range [0-10): 2
range [10-20): 3
range [30-40): 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F, '0<=$4 && $4<10{a++} 10<=$4 && $4<20{b++}  END{printf "range 0-10: %i range 10-20: %i\n",a,b}' foo.txt
range 0-10: 2 range 10-20: 3
```

#### How it works

- `0<=$4 && $4<10{a++}`

  This counts every time the fourth field is in [0,10).
- `10<=$4 && $4<20{b++}`

  This counts every time the fourth field is in [10,20).
- `END{printf "range 0-10: %i range 10-20: %i\n",a,b}`

  After we have finished reading the file, this prints out the results in the desired format.

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their code spread over multiple lines:

```
awk -F, '
    0<=$4 && $4<10 {
        a++
    } 

    10<=$4 && $4<20{
        b++
    }

    END{
        printf "range 0-10: %i range 10-20: %i\n", a, b
    }
    ' foo.txt
```

#### Modified version of original code

In awk, `$range1` is the value of field whose number is `range1`.  This is not what you want.  If you are not referencing a field number, do not use `$`.  Thus:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    range1=0;
    range2=0;
}
$4 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 >= 0 && $4 < 10 { range1 += 1 };
$4 ~ /[0-9]/ && $4 >= 10 && $4 < 20 { range2 += 1 };
END {
    print range1, "\t", range2;
}
```

Note that initializing the range variables to zero is not necessary: zero is the default value for a numeric variable.